# round or Trim after decimal

Tags: php, function

If My `$number` is equal to `4853.14248325523`

```
function formatMoney($number) {
        $replaced = preg_replace('/(-?\d+)(\d\d\d)/', '$1,$2', $number);
        if ($replaced != $number) {
            $number = $replaced;
        } 
    return '$'.$number;
}
```

my function `formatMoney()` will return a value of `$4,853.142483,25523`

However, I would like for the function to return the value of `$4,853.14`

Comment: What is `preg_replace('/(-?\d+)(\d\d\d)/', '$1,$2', $number);` suppose to do? Are you trying to use this to set thousands separators? If so, look at using [number_format()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) instead

Comment: Exactly what I am trying to do. I will update my stuff to number_format();

Comment: That doesnt allow my value to be changed to a $ amount and decimal.

Comment: What about `money_format()`?

Comment: Thank you, learned a few things :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

no need to roll your own with regular expressions, php has built in functions to handle this:

```
$number=4853.14248325523;

echo '$'.number_format($number,2, '.', ',');
```

above returns `$4,853.14`

manual page [number_format()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)

Answer (score 2):

PHP has a really nice [money_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php) function:

```
<?php

$number=4853.14248325523;
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_US');
echo money_format('%n', $number) . "\n";
```